# Target ul and li within div using css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to find a way to target the `<ul>` and `<li>` markups but only within a specific `<div>`, not for the entire page. I have this in the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar_div">
   <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

In the CSS I would like to do something like:

```
div#navbar_div {
    float:right;
}

div#navbar_div .ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#navbar_div .li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Remove the _dot_ in front of `ul` and `li` in your CSS

Comment: Remove the "." from ul and li in your css

Answer (score 17, accepted):

first thing is you should remove the `.` sign from the `ul` in your css.
we use `.` signt to define a **class** and `#` sign to define an **id**.
but for default elements or tags provided by html, we don't want to use those. we can use just there name.as an example if we put some style to body we can write like this.

```
body{
 background-color:black;
}
```

to get an better idea, I wrote a small code for you.hope this will help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
 }

/* add styles only to for 'ul' element, inside the id="one" div */
div#one ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 color: orange;
}


/* add style only to the 'li' elements inside the id="one" div. this means 'li' inside the 'ul' inside the 'div' which its id="one" */
div#one ul li{
 display: inline;
 margin: 20px;

}

</style>

<body>

 <div id="one">
  <ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
   <li>five</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="two">
  <ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
   <li>five</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the periods before `ul` and `li`. Periods signify classes. `ul` and `li` are native HTML tags, therefore you can reference them as they are.

Answer (score 2):

```
.navbar_div ul , .navbar li {
 //whatever goes here
}
```